# rich.prompt.Confirm not working in rich.Progress context python

Tags: python, progress-bar, rich

I am working on an app that uses a `rich.Progress` for rendering progress bars. The problem is `rich.prompt.Confirm` just flashes instead of showing the message and asking for the confirmation while in the `Progress` context.

Demo Code

```
from rich.progress import Progress
from rich.prompt import Confirm
from time import sleep

with Progress() as progress:
    task = progress.add_task('Cooking')
    while not progress.finished:
        if Confirm.ask('Should I continue', default=False):
            progress.update(task, advance=0.6)
            sleep(0.4)
```

**EDIT:** I have seen git issues and researched a bit and it seems `input`(which the `rich.Prompt` uses) doesn't work on any thing that uses `rich.Live`(which the `rich.Progress` uses). So now my question is, How can you structure your code so that you don't put a prompt inside a `rich.Progress` context manager. Or any possible workarounds to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the [Github Issue](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/1535#issuecomment-1711731104) (That might be the one you talked about), that is now a workaround, thanks to Leonardo Cencetti.
The solution is simple. He pause the progress and clear the progress lines. When you are done, he starts the progress again.

For Future people here is his code:

```py
from rich.progress import Progress
class PauseProgress:
    def __init__(self, progress: Progress) -> None:
        self._progress = progress

    def _clear_line(self) -> None:
        UP = "\x1b[1A"
        CLEAR = "\x1b[2K"
        for _ in self._progress.tasks:
            print(UP + CLEAR + UP)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._progress.stop()
        self._clear_line()
        return self._progress

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self._progress.start()
```

And in you MWC, it is going to be used like:

```py
from rich.progress import Progress
from rich.prompt import Confirm
from time import sleep

with Progress() as progress:
    task = progress.add_task('Cooking')
    while not progress.finished:
        with PauseProgress(progress):
            ok_to_go = Confirm.ask('Should I continue', default=False)
        if not ok_to_go:
            break
        progress.update(task, advance=0.6)
        sleep(1)
```